# Center a div under another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

My question is if someone could help me with positioning the "container-div" under the "settings-div". I also would like that even if someone would zoom in, that it would stay under the "settings-div".

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="option">Home</div>
        <div class="option">Media</div>
        <div class="option">link 3</div>
        <div class="option">link 4</div>
        <div class="option">link 5</div>
        <div class="open"></div>
        <div class="option" id="settings">Settings</div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="s-o">Account</div>
        <div class="s-o">Privacy</div>
        <div class="s-o">Logout</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    background-image: url("carbon_background.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cgoogleover;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #3B5998;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.menu .option {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3B5998;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menu .open {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3B5998;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.s-o {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 85%;
    background-color: #BBBBFF;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 15%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

[Here is a jsFiddle of my current script](http://jsfiddle.net/cLWeK/).

Comment: What problems have you encountered as you attempted to accomplish this?

Comment: That whenever I zoomed in, that it would move to the right or that it the 3 div's moved over eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need remove the margin's from the `body` element.

```
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

Then you can get rid of all those strange `-8px` margins on the `menu` element which are causing it to be out of alignment with everything else. You can get rid of the `top` and `left` properties too, since they aren't doing anything.

So your menu class just looks like this:

```
.menu {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #3B5998;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

At that point, I think your container div should line up perfectly.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cLWeK/1/

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was useful to you, you can upvote it too (click on the up arrow at the top of the answer).